# Keyboard shortcut for Control Center

Tags: macos, keyboard, control-center

How can I open Control Center without the mouse—only the keyboard?

[image: Screenshot of Control Center for context]

Answer (score 7):

Here are two ways to get into Control Center without the mouse on macOS.

---

### Option 1:

Using: *"Full Keyboard Access"* to navigate

- Settings found in: *System Preferences* → *Accessibility* → *Shortcut*

  - <kbd>Check</kbd> *"Full Keyboard Access"*
- Open: *Control Center* using <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Use: <kbd>Tab</kbd> /<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate

**Tip:**

- Activate *"Full Keyboard Access"* from shortcut <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + **<kbd>F5</kbd>** .
- Deselect all other accessibility shortcuts.
- Shortcut: "Show Accessibility controls" must be turned on

  - Go to: *System Preferences* → *Keyboard* → *Shortcuts* → *Accessibility* → at bottom
- "Full Keyboard Access" doesn't have to be activated to open "Control Center with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

**Note:**
*(I found navigating Control Center with keys a little hard in the beginning but with practice I'm sure it'll be easier. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> for Help and <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> for an Action Menu for each selected item.*

[image: screenshot of Accessibility shortcuts]

---

### Option 2 (my favorit)

##### 1. Record your actions with "Automator"

- Open: *Automator* → New: *Application*
- Record action: when you click the *Control Center* icon in status bar
- Keep clicking if you want more steps
- Save Application. Stores in */Users/[name]/Library/Services/[app name.app]* (mine was "Open Control Center.app")

**Tip:** Turn up Playback Speed to x10

##### 2. Launch new app with Quick Action + shortcut

- Open: *Automator* → New: *Quick Action*
- Search: *"Launch Application"* in Action Library → Drag into work area
- Choose your app in list: Select app "Other" or drag from Finder into little box
- Save Quick Action. Eg. "Launch Control Center"

Create shortcut to your new Quick Action/Service

- Go to: *System Preferences* → *Keyboard* → *Shortcuts* → *Services*
- At the bottom you'll find your action: General - [quickActionName]
- <kbd>Check</kbd> and give it your shortcut, eg. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

**Notes:**

- Might still requires mouse to navigate, but you're already there
- Doesn't work if you've hidden *Status Bar*
- If you move the CC-icon in status bar you'll have to re-record

**IMPORTANT!!**

- Must give Accessibility permissions to your new Application
- Go to: *System Preferences* → *Security & Privacy* → *Privacy* → *Accessibility*
- Unlock to make changes
- Add or drag your application to this list

Note: not the Quick Action that runs from your shortcut, but the first application you created that has the "Whach Me Do"

---

*Thanks @Merchako for the tip on <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it helped me get started on figuring out a way to control that window*

Answer (score 4):

Type <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to open Control Center.

As far as I know, there's no way to interact with it after opening it, but at least you can see the main status of each control.

—

I've only gotten this to work on the keyboards of M1 and M1 Max MacBooks (Monterey). It doesn't work with the Nuphy75 external keyboard (neither wired nor wireless).